# Android merging mp4 and aac file using mediamuxer mediacodec and mediaextractor (without mp4parser)

Tags: android, mp4, android-mediacodec, mediamuxer, mediaextractor

I am recording an audio, then trying to merge aac audio and mp4 video file(muted, without audio), and share the merged mp4 file. The sharing of merged mp4 file works in Samsung J2 and Xiaomi, but the mp4 file doesnot play in Lenovo, Micromax and other phones.The test results are mentioned here:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1eeJEM-v-smEUzY-bSxwIwFVOsAbv6KT2u3Kz3jdOb8o/edit?usp=sharing
 I am unable to understand the problem is due to share or due to improper muxing and also what is the cause of the issue. Please help.

code for sharing is present in recordAudio.java and is this:

```
public void shareVroom(View view) {
//    Toast.makeText(this, "Share feature is temporarily disabled", android.widget.Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

//    Toast.makeText(this, "Share feature is enabled", android.widget.Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        // Code commented for UAT

        try {
            MediaMultiplexer mediaMultiplexer = new MediaMultiplexer();
            mediaMultiplexer.startMuxing(this);

            Toast.makeText(this, "in share",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            String shareableFileName = "";

            Intent intentShareFile = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            shareableFileName = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
            shareableFileName += getString(R.string.vroom_video_output_file_name);
            File fileWithinMyDir = new File(shareableFileName);
            Uri videoUri=Uri.parse(shareableFileName);
            if (fileWithinMyDir.exists()) {
                intentShareFile.setType("video/mp4");
                intentShareFile.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, videoUri);
                intentShareFile.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Listen to my VROOM");
                intentShareFile.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Vroom attached");
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intentShareFile, "Share your Vroom with"));
            }

        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e("tag", e.getMessage(), e);
            Toast.makeText(this, "could not shared"+e.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }


        //TODO:Use event to identify if muxing is done

    }
```

Code for muxing:

```
public class MediaMultiplexer {
    private static final int MAX_SAMPLE_SIZE = 256 * 1024;

    public void startMuxing(Context context) {
        MediaMuxer muxer = null;
        MediaFormat VideoFormat = null;
        Resources mResources = context.getResources();
        int sourceVideo = R.raw.vid;
        String outputVideoFileName = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
        outputVideoFileName += context.getString(R.string.vroom_video_output_file_name);
        try {
            muxer = new MediaMuxer(outputVideoFileName, MediaMuxer.OutputFormat.MUXER_OUTPUT_MPEG_4);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        MediaExtractor extractorVideo = new MediaExtractor();
        try {
            AssetFileDescriptor srcVideoFd = mResources.openRawResourceFd(sourceVideo);
            extractorVideo.setDataSource(srcVideoFd.getFileDescriptor(), srcVideoFd.getStartOffset(), srcVideoFd.getLength());
            int tracks = extractorVideo.getTrackCount();
            for (int i = 0; i < tracks; i++) {
                MediaFormat mf = extractorVideo.getTrackFormat(i);
                String mime = mf.getString(MediaFormat.KEY_MIME);
                if (mime.startsWith("video/")) {
                    extractorVideo.selectTrack(i);
                    VideoFormat = extractorVideo.getTrackFormat(i);
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        MediaExtractor extractorAudio = new MediaExtractor();
        try {
            String audioFileName = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
            audioFileName += context.getString(R.string.vroom_audio_file_name);
            extractorAudio.setDataSource(audioFileName);
            int tracks = extractorAudio.getTrackCount();
//            Toast.makeText(context, "No of tracks::::" + String.valueOf(tracks), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            extractorAudio.selectTrack(0);

            MediaFormat AudioFormat = extractorAudio.getTrackFormat(0);
            int audioTrackIndex = muxer.addTrack(AudioFormat);
            int videoTrackIndex = muxer.addTrack(VideoFormat);

            boolean sawEOS = false;
            boolean sawAudioEOS = false;
            int bufferSize = MAX_SAMPLE_SIZE;
            ByteBuffer dstBuf = ByteBuffer.allocate(bufferSize);
            int offset = 100;
            MediaCodec.BufferInfo bufferInfo = new MediaCodec.BufferInfo();
            muxer.start();

            while (!sawEOS) {
                bufferInfo.offset = offset;
                bufferInfo.size = extractorVideo.readSampleData(dstBuf, offset);
                if (bufferInfo.size < 0) {
                    sawEOS = true;
                    bufferInfo.size = 0;
                } else {
                    bufferInfo.presentationTimeUs = extractorVideo.getSampleTime();
                    bufferInfo.flags = extractorVideo.getSampleFlags();
                    int trackIndex = extractorVideo.getSampleTrackIndex();
                    muxer.writeSampleData(videoTrackIndex, dstBuf, bufferInfo);
                    extractorVideo.advance();
                }
            }
            ByteBuffer audioBuf = ByteBuffer.allocate(bufferSize);
            while (!sawAudioEOS) {
                bufferInfo.offset = offset;
                bufferInfo.size = extractorAudio.readSampleData(audioBuf, offset);
                if (bufferInfo.size < 0) {
                    sawAudioEOS = true;
                    bufferInfo.size = 0;
                } else {
                    bufferInfo.presentationTimeUs = extractorAudio.getSampleTime();
                    bufferInfo.flags = extractorAudio.getSampleFlags();
                    int trackIndex = extractorAudio.getSampleTrackIndex();
                    muxer.writeSampleData(audioTrackIndex, audioBuf, bufferInfo);
                    extractorAudio.advance();
                }
            }
            muxer.stop();
            muxer.release();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: I fixed your code block. The easiest way to format a code block on SO is to paste it into your question, select it, and press Ctrl+K or click the `{}` button. This will indent the block by an additional four spaces, which tells Stack Overflow to treat it as code. You can read more about formatting in the [help centre](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Comment: Download a tool called `mediaInfo` and tell us codec settings. If the video's h.264 Profile is "High" then it may not be playable in some devices, use "Baseline" for maximum device compatibility. Is your audio AAC or MP3? Also check that the audio has a 44.1 kilo-hertz for sample-rate, is stereo, etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

changed the audio output format and encoder to AMR_NB